# Getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'greetingControler' available  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstracBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
>     at
>   vill.example.village.VillageApplication.main(VillageApplication.java:15)

**The class that generates this exception is**

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import services.GreetingService;

@Controller
public class GreetingControler {
    private GreetingService greetingService;

    @Autowired
    public void setGreetingService(GreetingService greetingService) {
        this.greetingService = greetingService;
    }
    public String sayHello()
    {
        String greeting=greetingService.getGreeting();
        System.out.println(greeting);
        return  greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read this, then fix your package layout.: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

Answer (score 4):

Replace the method setGreetingService(GreetingService greetingService) with class constructor.

```
@Autowired
public GreetingControler (GreetingService greetingService) {
    this.greetingService = greetingService;
}
```